# Why am I getting weird curved lines on photos taken in light on my sony cybershot?

Tags: camera-settings, sony, camera, error

The photos I take on my Cybershot have these horizontal lines all over the place. These lines are curved at some points and as you zoom in it acts really weird and changes.

[image: example of curved banding]

The thing is, this happens only when **there is light**.  The pictures end up looking bad regardless of the source of light I am using, be it natural sunlight or fluorescent.

When there is no light, or when I shoot in pitch black, it works as it should and gives really good photos.

The camera does show an error code `E:62:10`, but it used to work fine till last day with the error code. I couldn't record video with it, but by a simple hack (pressing the left circle button and then the shutter) I could start recording and I still can record good quality videos.

I tried initializing (resetting) the camera. Is it a problem with the sensor?

Comment: What is that a photograph of?  What camera model?

Comment: @xiota thats a white wall. Cybershot dsc w830

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error E:62:10 is "lens error". 
Most likely the lens has lost its alignment with the sensor, maybe because it is bent or twisted a tiny bit out of shape.

This can cause the lines you see, as the camera is trying to compensate for an expected image from the lens, but the actual image is skewed.

Comment: Is there anything that I can do except for taking it to the service center?

Comment: You could try to check the lens. Does it extend and detract as it should? Does it appear to be bent? Does it make scraping noises?. Is it wiggly when fully extended? If so there isn’t much that can be done but taking it for repair or trying to figure out if you can fix it yourself,

Answer (score 1):

The change when you zoom in is just a [moiré effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern) between the lines in your picture and the pixels of your screen (and the scaling which is applied by your image viewer).

The question is why you have these "scan lines". My hypothesis that your sensor (or some electronics downstream) is failing, so every other line is slightly darker than it should. The pincushion shape could be due to the firmware correcting a barrel distortion (this shape would change a bit depending on focal length).